# jquery unbind or off click event handler within specific parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons, and all of them have event handlers on click.

If a button is within a specific parent, then there should be no click event on the button. But rather, a click event should exist at that specifc parent level itself.

In the code below, on clicking the button within `.case2`, I was expecting the alert to show "case2 parent clicked", but it still shows the alert "button clicked".

Why is that happening ? And how do I correct it ?

Thanks.

```js
    $('.button').on('click', function (e) {
        alert('button clicked');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });


    $('.case2')
            .off('click', '.button', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            })
            .on('click', function (e) {
                alert('case2 parent clicked');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
```

```css
.case1, .case2, .case3 {
  margin:1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #0b97c4;
  width: 5em;
  height:2em;
}

.button {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case1">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="case2">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="case3">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use an anonymous function as the handler in `.off()`. That argument means "If there's a handler that runs this function, remove it". But since it's an anonymous function, it can't be the same as the handler that was previously added.

Comment: from [jQuery .off() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/): "A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers." So I don't believe it's actually removing the eventhandler set on the button. Try `$('.case2 .button').off('click').parent().on('click','.button',function(e){ your function stuff });`

Comment: @Barmar actually passing a function parameter to `.off()` is useful if you're looking to clear a *specific* handler that was bound. However, I don't know if it can be an anonymous function to be honest. Regardless, I think it's because he's calling `.off()` on the parent rather than on the button, and the parent doesn't have an eventhandler matching that criteria.

Comment: @ShamSUP I know yuo can pass a function as a parameter. It just doesn't make sense to pass an anonymous function, because it can't be the same as the function that was bound, since every anonymous function is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not` in the selector.

```js
$('.button:not(.case2 .button)').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('button clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.case2').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('case2 parent clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.case1, .case2, .case3 {
  margin:1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #0b97c4;
  width: 5em;
  height:2em;
}

.button {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case1">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="case2">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="case3">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for an alternate example, simply only attach the handler and not turn it off.

```
var buttons = $('.button');
buttons.not('.case2 .button').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('case first');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
buttons.parents('.case2').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('case2 parent clicked');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the ".button" class to your selector:

```
$(".class2 .button").on("click",function(e){
    alert('button')
    e.stopPropagation()
 })
```

and it shoud fire first.